# Redirect with htaccess changing URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect

`www.mydomain.net/folder/site/somepage.php` to `www.mysite.net/somepage.php`

With the caveat being that `www.mydomain.net/folder/site/` is the root public folder for mysite.net. So basically, I don't want users to get there via:

```
www.mydomain.net/folder/site/somepage.php
```

but rather

```
www.mysite.net/somepage.php
```

even though these are really the same location on the server. I am not sure how to eliminate the `/folder/` part of the path when it gets rewritten.

Comment: Please post some more information like which web server are you using, if it is apache, please post your current `.htaccess`. If the webserver is Apache, your functionality can be achieved using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html),

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following .htaccess code to do what you are asking for, I've looked around to see what I could come up with, and I think this is the best way possible:

```
#With mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/somepage.php"  "/folder/site/somepage.php"  [R,L]
```

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: That does not do anything to change the domain. Also "somepage" needs to be a wild card. This is because I have 4 sites hosted on one server but three of them are in a subfolder /other/site1  /other/site2  /other/site3 and I need to rewrite the URL so that anything in for example /other/site3 gets rewritten to www.site3.net/...and then whatever was beyond the above path.

Comment: Oh right sorry, must have misunderstood you there. I don't know if that's possible to do if you've got more than one domain on the server, possibly using a PHP script might work but that's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this works:

RedirectMatch ^/folderName/(.*)$ http://www.newsite.net/$1

Comment: This rule would not work with the url as described in the question itself.